# APK app download with PHP

Tags: php, android

When I transfer an app with B4A Bridge or per cable, everyrthing runs perfectly.

When I put it on my server for testers to download, the download is successful, but then I get "Parsing error: An error occured during parsing of the packet".

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="main.apk"');
header("Content-Length: 11111"); // size oif APK-file in byte
readfile('main.apk');
?>
```

I also tried

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="main.apk"');
$apk = file_get_contents('main.apk');
header("Content-Length: ".strlen($apk)); 
print($apk);
?>
```

Windows Server 2012 R2, IIS.

Thank you

Peter

Answer (score 0):

You must use:

Content-type: application/jar

Content-type: application/apk

And your for your "content-lenght" use filesize() function. [filesize() php doc](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filesize.php)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!

Like this? Same result.

```
header('Content-Type: application/jar');
header('Content-Type: application/apk');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="main.apk"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize ("main.apk"));
readfile('main.apk');
```